# In Magento to Import a Database to a new template how can you delete all the tables related to design and template features?

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9, centos6

We just moved to a new Magento Template. We want to move our database, but when we import the DB to the new server it affects severely the design of the new template any advice on how to solve this?

He just want to import clients, orders, sales, historic sales, & configurations.

Magento Version 1.9.2
Centos 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: Show your efforts and code!

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I want o just export the:

clients catalog sales configuration

Not really code wise but how to to edit or partially import the database?

The only idea so far is to edit tabe by table thru phpmyadmin, but is there any other more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I want o just export the:

clients
catalog
sales
configuration

Not really code wise but how to to edit or partially import the database?

The only idea so far is to edit tabe by table thru phpmyadmin, but is there any other more efficient way?